# Setting PERL5LIB

Tags: perl

Can I set PERL5LIB in a separate script and call that script in other scripts? How do I do it? And how would it affect the script in which it is used?

Answer (score 8):

Setting `PERL5LIB` at runtime will not affect Perl's search path. You need to export the variable before executing the interpreter.
Alternatively you can modify `@INC` at compile time (also possible to do in a separate script/module):

```
BEGIN { unshift @INC, "/path/to/dir" }
```

This is what the `lib` pragma does.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I think because the PERL5LIB environment variable is processed by the interpreter before the script is executed, so @INC isn't modified.

Answer (score 5):

You'd do this via 'use lib' rather than manipulating the environment:

```
use lib '/home/perl5';
```

That could be in a separate file that you 'require' in.

Answer (score 3):

`PERL5INC` is a *shell* environment variable, so you wouldn't set it inside your Perl program (normally) but instead specify it before invoking Perl. The below is a shell command where I've used `PERL5LIB` to instruct [`prove`](http://blogs.perl.org/users/confuseacat/2011/09/perl-testing-with-jenkinshudson-avoiding-some-pitfalls.html) to find a Perl module residing in `~/OnePop`:

```
$ PERL5LIB=~/OnePop prove -l t
... PERL5LIB is unset here ....
```

When a command is preceded by a variable assignment like this, the shell sets and exports the variable (`PERL5LIB`) to that command, but after that the variable will be unset again. You can also set the variable in the shell, so that all subsequent commands will inherit it.

```
$ export PERL5LIB=~/OnePop
...
$ prove -l t
... PERL5LIB continues to be set here ...
```

If you forget the `export` keyword in the above example (i.e. assigns the value using `PERL5LIB=~/OnePop` on a separate line) the variable will be set *in the shell,* but it will *not* be inherited by any commands you run (meaning that `prove` will not be able to see it).

Finally, if you wanted to set the environment `PERL5LIB` variable from inside a Perl program you'd have to write it like this:

```
$ENV{PERL5LIB} = glob("~/OnePop");   # glob() expands the tilde
system(qw( prove -l t ));
```

Though, as other have pointed out, if you want to specify the include path from inside Perl it is easier/better to use `use lib $PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

PERL5INC is an environment variable. Environment variables are only inherited from parents to their children and can't (easily) be set the other way around. If you want to store extra search paths in an external file I suggest you make it a simple list of paths and write a simple loop to read each path from the file and manipulate @INC in the current process. If you want this to be done early at compile time you'll have to use a BEGIN {} block.

For example

```
BEGIN{
  open(INCFILE,"<","my.inc.file") or die($!);
  foreach(<INCFILE>){
    push @INC,$_;
  }
  close(INCFILE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative to PERL5LIB:

You could instead install the latest version of Perl 5 available (in a non-system location, of course). After you have used a module file or done whatever is necessary to make the new `perl` and `cpan` executables visible to your shell, you can use `cpan` to install all the modules you need. I have sometimes done this for individual applications in a similar vein to using Python Virtual Environments.